# Why do we assume electrons experience lattice potentials in solids?

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics

Why don't we assume the protons wave function spreads out uniformly and just provides a uniform background potential?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, the assumption of a uniform density neutralizing background is called the [free electron model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_electron_model) and is one of the first steps we take in the analysis of electronic properties of solids. Unfortunately, while the model makes multiple successful predictions (e.g., the Wiedemann-Franz law at high temperature), experimental evidence such as the temperature dependences of the electrical conductivity and the specific heat reveal it to be inadequate.

Comment: This answer would be clearer if the word "this" in the first sentence were defined.

Comment: Thats interesting, Thanks.  So why assume a latice as apposed to some other sort of distribution of protons?

Comment: Scientists have understood that crystals are composed of regularly stacked "sheets" for hundreds of years based on the shearing of crystals and formation of faces. Once x-rays were discovered, X-ray diffraction/crystallography could be use to more directly confirm the periodic arrangements of atoms.